# Pegar a 2 posição de uma string em uma array

Tags: javascript

eu estou com uma dificuldade de pegar apenas a "segunda posiçao" de cada string em um conjunto de array.

Exemplo: ao jogar as urls abaixo:

https://www.devs.com/produto/chave1,
https://www.devs.com/produto/chave2

Eu quero recuperar apenas o sufixo de cada array que no caso seria, "chave1", "chave2" e assim por diante independentemente da quantidade de links que eu colocar.

Tentei fazer aqui, mas ao rodar o código abaixo, ele busca os 2 itens:

[
    " https://www.devs.com",
    "chave1"
  ],

```js
function myFunction() {
  
  
  var exibir = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;

  result = exibir.split(',').map(s => s.split('/produto/'))
  
  console.log(result)

  let display = result

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>A demonstration of how to access a TEXTAREA element</h3>

Address:<br>
<textarea id="myTextarea">
 https://www.devs.com/produto/chave1,
https://www.devs.com/produto/chave2
</textarea>

<p>Click the button to get the content of the text area.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Alguém sabe como eu faço para capturar apenas o que vier depois de /produto/ que no caso seria "chave1", chave2", e assim por diante?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta usar um `map` para percorrer item por item do `array` e depois, em cada item, usar a função `split` para pegar o último grupo separado por `/`:

```js
const links = ['https://www.devs.com/produto/chave1', 'https://www.devs.com/produto/chave2'];
const chaves = links.map((link) => link.split('/')[link.split('/').length - 1]);
console.log(chaves);
```

> [**String.prototype.split()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
>
> O método `split()` divide um objeto `String` em um `array` de `strings` ao separar a `string` em `substrings`.

---

> [**Array.prototype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
>
> O método map() invoca a função callback passada por argumento para cada elemento do Array e devolve um novo Array como resultado.
>
> ```
> var numbers = [1, 4, 9];
> var roots = numbers.map(Math.sqrt);
> // roots é [1, 2, 3], numbers ainda é [1, 4, 9]
> ```

Comment: Valeu cara, muito obrigado pela explicação!

Comment: @Thiago se a resposta lhe ajudou, não esqueça de aceitá-la como correta para o seu questionamento, auxiliando assim pessoas com dúvidas similares a encontrá-la.

Comment: Claro, valeu mano!

Comment: dúvida aqui, estou quebrando a cabeça para colocar o input do textarea na const links, tipo eu quero que o usuário coloque todos os links na caixa de texto e apareça no navegador, como eu faço isso?

Answer (score 0):

O split divide a sua string em duas partes, como você só precisa da segunda parte é melhor aplicar um substring dessa forma:

```js
var link = 'https://www.devs.com/produto/chave1'
var pagina = '/produto/'

var chave = link.substring(link.search(pagina) + pagina.length, link.length)
console.log(chave)
```